# Ошибка не отображается в списке ошибок Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Ошибки в коде перестали отображаться в списке ошибок. Проект давно не запускал, переустановил винду на вин 10 и заново установил визуалку с момента последнего запуска проекта.
[image: Сообщение об ошибке]

После того как очистил и пересобрал.
[image: После того как очистил и пересобрал]

Подозрительная ошибка сообщающая о невозможности проанализировать весь проект.
[image: Подозрительная ошибка]

Comment: Перезагруть VS и Clean and Rebuild Solution вы уже попробовали? Либо удалить  .suo файлы. Вариантов масса. Может вы вывод ошибок куда-то в файл настроили?

Comment: Попробуйте еще поставить в списке отображаемых ошибок вместо опции `Build Only` опицию `Build + Intellisen` (находится правее от кнопок Errors Warnings Messages)

Comment: @koks_rs Обычный файл проект. Ничего не настраивал с выводом ошибок. "Build + Intellisen" не помогло. Почистил и перестроил проект - ничего не изменилось. Запустил анализатор кода - 30 варнингов 0 эроров.

Comment: судя по скриншоту вы уже определили что у вас какая-то библиотека отвалилась? Проверьте что путь к этой либе не остался с прошлой OS. Удалите ее и добавьте снова

Comment: @koks_rs спасибо. Вечером отпишусь!